# Epoch time is giving difference of 12:hours

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting error of 12:00 house

Suppose response in epoch time is **1454092200000**
and its corresponding time is `1/30/2016, 12:00:00 AM GMT+5:30`

```
$scope.shipmentDate = moment(1454092200000).format("YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm");
```

But this convert into `1/30/2016, 12:00:00`  which is 12:00 P.M, why?

Comment: Have your format string output the am/pm modifier as well (`a`) – what do you get then?

Comment: (And perhaps check the timezone as well, `z` – but that requires moment-timezone too.)

Comment: @CBroe how I format string based on am/pm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use HH if you need the 00 - 23 hours format